# stop location when stop application

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, terminate

i've developped an iOS application.

I have a location manager wich get my location when I'm in app.

When I enter into background state, I want to my location continue to updated and send local notification when change. (this part is OK).

My problem is location manager still use location when I kill app.

I want to stop location updating when app terminate.

I try to use this function :

```
- (void) applicationWillTerminate
```

But it never pass into this function ...

Any ideas ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: No, when I init my locationManager I do that :           self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 200.0f;
        self.currentLocation = nil;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: do you want your app to run in the background, or fully exit when the user closes it?  `applicationWillTerminate:` does not get called if the user closes your app, and it goes into the background.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are properly shutting down the location monitoring/GPS when the application is terminated.

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

If everything is set up correctly, the location will continue in the background or via delegate methods and wake your app up to respond to them.